# "There's something wrong among us" or "There's something wrong between us"?

Tags: word-choice, among-between

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“between” vs “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

If I, for example, have a misunderstand with my partner, and talking with another person about it, should I say "There's something wrong among us" or "There's something wrong between us" (to mean "she and me")?