# "Difference between" multiple choices (vs. "among")

Tags: prepositions, questions, comparisons, among-between

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“between” vs “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

I learned that "between" refers to two objects or concepts and "among" refers to three or more. However, in situations when I am asking about distinctions, it seems correct to say, for example, "What is the difference between a horse, a zebra, and a mule?" as opposed to saying, "What is the difference among a horse, a zebra, and a mule?"

What is the rule for questions like this about the "differences between" several things?

Comment: The rule is: > **If you are a native English speaker, say what sounds right to you. And write it, too.** If you are **not** a native English speaker, ask a native speaker ***which one "sounds better"*** (but **not** *which one is correct* -- native English speakers are taught a lot of very strange ideas about so-called "*correctness"*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was taught:

> - **Use *between* when you're talking about individual items** -- even if there are more than two of them: "She was stuck between a Rock, a
>     Hard Place, and a Hard Rock Cafe."
> - **Use *among* when you're talking about things that aren't distinct**: "Dissension and dissatisfaction spread among the followers of Binky."

Grammar Girl must have had [the same teacher](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/between-versus-among.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, so according to this it would be correct to say, "The item was discussed between the five committee members."

Comment: @jrdioko No, _five committee members_ does not describe **distinct** entities; now, if you said "...discussed between Manny, Moe, Jack, Groucho, and Harpo," that would be correct by this guideline.

Comment: @jrdioko Read the [Grammar Girl article](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/between-versus-among.aspx).

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is:

> **If you are a native English speaker, say what sounds right to you. And write it, too.**

If you are **not** a native English speaker, ask a native speaker ***which one "sounds better"*** (but **not** *which one is correct* -- native English speakers are taught a lot of very strange ideas about so-called "*correctness"*).