# Is "between" always used for two things?

Tags: meaning, among-between

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“between” vs “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

I know the word **"between"** is used when we are concerned with two things. But can it be used with more than two things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *OED*, **between** usually involves only two limits, but when boundaries are concerned, there may be more than two limits. For e.g.,

> Switzerland lies ***between*** France, Italy, Austria and Germany.
>
> Our house is ***between*** the wood, the river and the village.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sometimes you do (and must) use *between* for **more** than two things alone. In these places, you cannot swap in *among*, or it will sound wrong.

For example, *between* can be used with several points of geography:

> My territory lies ***between*** Denver, Dallas, and Chicago.

and not

> My territory lies ****among*** Denver, Dallas, and Chicago.

It can also be used with people, as in:

> ***Between*** your sister, your brother, and your cousin, we’ll get this sorted out.

and not

> ****Among*** your sister, your brother, and your cousin, we’ll get this sorted out.

As you see, one cannot substitute in *among* for *between* in those examples, even though three things are involved in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the word "Between" can be used for more than two things. For example , "The discussion was between three people" or us three or Jack, John and Mike .