# "Find a new job between the posted jobs" or "Find a new job among the posted jobs"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, among-between

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“between” vs “among”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

I have a question which one of these two is the correct sentence:

> Find a new job between the posted jobs.

or

> Find a new job among the posted jobs.

Comment: I think the latter "Finding a new job among the posted jobs" is the correct sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either. *Between* is normally used with only two options, but it can be used with many. *Among* can be used with any number (greater than one) of options, although the dictionary suggests three or more.

[**Between**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/between?q=Between)

> *preposition*
>
> (4) with reference to a choice or differentiation involving two or more things being considered together: "you have to choose between two or three different options"

[**Among**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/among?q=among)

> *preposition*
>
> (4) indicating a division, choice, or differentiation involving three or more participants:
> "the old king called the three princesses to divide his kingdom among them"
> "the State Council would elect a temporary president from among its members"

However, because you are using the verb *find*, it makes more sense to use *among* because of how *between* works with *find*, *search*, *look*, and similar verbs. When using verbs that give the impression of looking then *between* suggests gaps rather than the items themselves.

For example:

> What you are looking for is between the islands

This means that what is sought is not on the islands - so in the water.

Your example of

> Find a new job between the posted jobs.

gives me the impression that the posted jobs will not hold the job I am looking for, but it will perhaps be on the job board itself, rather than the individual postings.

Given this expectation that *between* raises, I recommend *among* over *between* for your sentence.