# What if any differences exist between ‘exchanges between’ and ‘exchanges among’?

Tags: meaning, differences, among-between

In the following phrase:

> The film offers a considerable number of long takes, making use of the
> technique to lace the film with comedy but also to quiet the need for
> more energetic forward movement of plot so that the subtle exchanges
> **between and among** characters might resound more deeply.

Why would the author have written *“between **and** among”* in this way? I understand the meaning of *“exchanges **between**”*, but not the meaning of *“exchanges **among**”*. What is the difference, whether real or implied, between those two terms here?

Comment: *Between* and *among* are near-synonyms. Some people believe *between* can only be used with 2 people/things, and *among* with more than 2, so they may be trying to be comprehensive.

Comment: 'Exchanges among' is probably included to refer to those conversations that are not one-to-one.

Comment: @StuartF While there are indeed some who “believe” this, they’re wrong.  There is, alas, no end of massively copycatted popular mythologizing going on between *between* and *betwixt* on the one hand and between *amid(st)* and *among(st)* on the other. See for example: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193840/2085), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/274938/2085), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69924/2085), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/122925/2085). [....]

Comment: [....] This erroneous “belief” can and does lead to the generation of ungrammatical constructions. The OED notes some of these when they write: **“[*Between*] is still the only word available to express the relation of a thing to many surrounding things severally and individually, *among* expressing a relation to them collectively and vaguely: we should not say ‘the space lying among the three points,’ or ‘a treaty among three powers,’ or ‘the choice lies among the three candidates in the select list,’ or ‘to insert a needle among the closed petals of a flower.’ ”**

Comment: Moha, does [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among) answer your question, perhaps supplemented with @EdwinAshworth’s comment?