# "On the equivalence of A and B" or "between A and B"

Tags: prepositions, synonyms, titles, prepositional-phrases, academia

I am writing an academic paper with a choice of titles:

> 1. On the equivalence of A and B
> 2. On the equivalence between A and B

or

> 1. On the equivalence of A, B and C
> 2. On the equivalence between A, B and C
> 3. On the equivalence among A, B and C

where A,B,C are some scientific or math notions.

Should I use **of** or **between** or **among**? Which case is more correct or suitable?

Comment: Let's stick with two, OK? The first two suggest a different emphasis. (1) is a demonstration that A and B are equivalent, while (2) is a discussion about the nature of the equivalence, and perhaps its evolution, variation, and implications.

Comment: @ John, This is useful. Now I know which one I aim for.

Comment: Another part of the answer is that you should use **between** when talking about two things, and **among** for three or more.

Comment: @Scott: I do not think you can say that as a definitive rule. See [an earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/37640/4333)

Comment: @Scott that rule smells like prescriptivist nonsense. These days they're probably effectively synonymous and I see no reason to make up rules for them.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically and semantically, both options seem correct. **Statistically**, you're better off going with "of A and B".

A quick search on Google Scholar shows there are **141,000 occurrences of "equivalence of * and"** and **59,600 occurrences of "equivalence between * and."**

"Of" is roughly* 2.38 times more likely to be used in academic writing.

[* There is a fair amount of extrapolation since Google Scholar doesn't index the entire body of research out there, but there is no reason to assume it isn't a representative sample. ]

Comment: @ Guybrush Threepwood, thanks for the comment, +1.