# difference in meaning depending on placement of "already"

Tags: meaning, differences, word-order, adverb-position

1. Maybe the bus already left.
2. Maybe the bus has already left.
3. Maybe the bus has left already.

I am not a native speaker so don't know if there is any difference among those three sentences, not knowing if there is any grammatical error as well.

Which one is the best??

Comment: [You cannot say "the difference among".  That is ungrammatical. It must be "difference between".](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193840/2085)

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example, there is really no meaningful difference. All three are equally grammatical, sound normal if spoken, and would be understood by a native speaker to mean the same thing.

Other sentences and other adverbs might allow more placements and entail subtle variations in meaning. But in your examples, I can see no other valid place to put "already".