# usage of amid instead of between

Tags: grammar, word-usage, collocation

Can I replace between with amid here?

> The engineers need to design the relationship **between** these function blocks.

Turning into

> The engineers need to design the relationship **amid** these function blocks.

Comment: You could use "among".

Comment: @HotLicks, I am not a native english speaker but it seems among has a similar problem that amid has.

Comment: No, because "among" is referring to a relationship, vs simply position.

Comment: @HotLicks No, only *between* can be used here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [“between” vs. “among”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)

Comment: @tchrist no. it is about using it in this mathematical case. I have seen that post and based on that I am asking this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No.

*Between* is used in sense (3) from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/between:

> a :  from one to another of 
>    b :  serving to connect or unite in a relationship (as difference, likeness, or proportion)

whereas *amid* has only its primary meaning (from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amid):

> : in or into the middle of (something)

The use of *amid* in your sentence therefore give us the sense that the engineers must be physically standing in the middle of a group of function blocks while they design the relationship (which does not necessarily relate to the function blocks at all), which is clearly not a reasonable meaning.