# “as schedule” vs. “as scheduled”

Tags: word-usage, differences, prepositions

You say *on schedule* or *behind schedule* which consist of:

> [preposition] + *schedule* (noun)

However, you say *as scheduled* and not *as schedule.* Why? What are the differences between these phrases?

Comment: When you are saying 'on schedule' or 'behind schedule', 'schedule' is a noun. You are describing the task relative to the schedule. In the case of 'as scheduled', 'schedule' is a verb, you did the scheduling in the past, so it is 'as scheduled'

Comment: @tchrist: I disagree. What's your source for that? [Here's](http://data.grammarbook.com/blog/adjectives-adverbs/different-from-vs-different-than/) another opinion. *Between* is appropriate if there are only two things being checked for differences. But with 3 or more things, *among* can be appropriate. [Here's](http://www.public.asu.edu/~gelderen/314text/chap2.htm) another example (a text about English grammar, no less) where you'll find both used (appropriately, IMO).

Comment: @tchrist: Please read what I said. I said nothing prescriptive (in particular, I did not say that *between* cannot be used with more than 2). I am not propagating any "myth", "prescriptivist poppycock" or otherwise. You seem to have an agenda (which resembles prescribing, even if you do not think of yourself as prescriptivist). I do not. And yes, I still disagree. I'm saying nothing about what one must or should use. I'm talking about how the words are used. It is you, not I, who claims that X is "*ungrammatical*" and it "*must be*" Y. That (prescriptivist poppycock?) is what I disagree with.

Comment: @tchrist: What makes it "wrong", beyond someone's prescription that it should not be said?  What makes it *ungrammatical*, in your eyes? FWIW, I agree with what is said (succinctly) in these two answers right next to yours (which approaches a rant): [1](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/37637/51214), [2](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/37644/51214). (And no, I do not interpret the "rule" expressed by #1 as prescriptive. It just describes actual use.)

Comment: @tchrist: That *you* cannot say it does not make it ungrammatical, to my mind. I can say it, and so can many others. And not at all because we were told to. That's your error, methinks: You rightfully rebel against someone speaking in an artificial way from following some misguided rule. But you mistake how many people actually speak (naturally) for rule-following. In particular, the nuance that *among* can suggest sharing (which you acknowledge, BTW: OED says "collectively and vaguely") and *between* can suggest one-to-one relationships is useful. Again, see #2, cited above.

Comment: @tchrist: You cite [Safire's article](http://www.nytimes.com/1993/09/12/magazine/on-language-betwixt-among-and-between.html), where he decries blindly following prescribed rules and supports following your ear. I do too. He is not saying what you seem to be saying (which sounds like prescribing, to me). And note that he says specifically, as I would say too, "*I usually use between when separating two, and among when discussing more than two, because I want to, not because I have to.*" He's following his ear, as am I.

Answer (score 2):

Phrases such as *[on schedule](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+schedule)* and *[behind schedule](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/behind+schedule)* are idioms, so the form,

> [preposition] + schedule (noun)

is not something that can be applied to every preposition and noun. However, *as schedule* is not commonly used. The phrase, *[as scheduled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20scheduled)* can be used in the following ways,

> Everything is going as scheduled.
>
> The food arrived as scheduled.

*As scheduled* is very similar to *on schedule* in that they are both used to describe an event that occurred on time or as expected. When one says something is *behind schedule*, then there is an indication that something failed to be done by a deadline. Some examples with *on schedule* and *behind schedule*,

> He came right on schedule for the baby shower.
>
> As long as every team member continues to his or her tasks on schedule, the project should be finished by February.
>
> The boarding process for our flight is behind schedule, so we have to wait another half-hour.
>
> The professor was behind schedule on his lectures and may ask the students to learn more material on their own.

Comment: It might be worth drawing attention to how *as scheduled* uses *as* plus a (passive) past participle, just like *as expected, as indicated, as specified, as found, as drawn, as shown, as spoken, as seen, as written, as told*.