# There are disagreements between/among......?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

There are disagreements between/among them(more than two people).

Should I use between or among in the sentence?

Comment: The post [between vs among](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among) didn't help you?

Comment: @clare I don't know which preposition I should use here.

Comment: Read the linked post. Your question has been asked here  before, many times. You could also look up both words in the dictionary and look for usage notes.

Answer (score -3):

Between is used for two people and Among is used for more than two people.